# Why do I get @firstname and @lastname in my SQL table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the following code in my ASP.NET project and I still can't figure out why is my SQL Server table saving the parameters name instead of the values. Any help will be appreciated.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void InsertMethod(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=KIMBERLY\SQLSERVER02;Initial Catalog=Chalegh;User ID=***;Password=***");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into TestTable values('@Firstname','@Lastname')", con);

    SqlParameter paramFirstName = new SqlParameter();
    paramFirstName.ParameterName = "@Firstname";
    paramFirstName.Value = firstname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFirstName);

    SqlParameter paramLastName = new SqlParameter();
    paramLastName.ParameterName = "@Lastname";
    paramLastName.Value = lastname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramLastName);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Just a side-note: you should use specific column names in your INSERT statement, otherwise if you add/reorder columns later everything breaks, e.g. `INSER INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove quotation marks and use [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into TestTable values(@Firstname,@Lastname)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname",firstname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname",lastname);
```

Your actual problem is *quotation marks*.When you use quotation marks `@Firstname` and `@Lastname` are treated as actual values instead of parameters.You don't have to use `AddWithValue` method but it's shorter and easy to use.You don't need to create `SqlParameter` for each parameter and set each property one by one.